# Creating a google calendar entry from a google form submission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api, google-forms

Trying to set up a google form that will automatically make a calendar entry for a community calendar.
Google form questions and how they appear in the related google sheet are

1. Email (column B)
2. eventName (column C)
3. eventDate (column D)
4. startTime (column E)
5. enfTime (column F)
6. eventLocation (column G)
7. eventDescription (column H)

Using App script in the Google Sheet I have written the following:

```
function myFunction() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form responses 1");
  var last_row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var data = sheet.getRange("A1:H" + last_row).getValues();
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("******@gmail.com");
  //Logger.log(data);

  for(var i = 0; i< data.length;i++){
    //index 0 =
    var event = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar()
    .createEvent(data[i][2],
    new Date(data[i][4]),
    new Date(data[i][3]),
    new Date(data[i][5]),
    new Date(data[i][7]),
    {location: data[i][6]});

 Logger.log('Event ID: ' + event.getId());
    
  }

}
```

I now get this error on run

Error - Exception: The parameters (String,(class),(class),(class),(class),(class)) don't match the method signature for CalendarApp.Calendar.createEvent. myFunction @ Code.gs:13

I am not experienced enough to solve it!

I was expecting it to populate a single calendar entry from a single form submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for createEvent() is:

- `createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, options)`
- String, Date, Date, options
- `startTime` and `endTime` are "the **date and time** when the event starts" - this requires add the date and time from the form submission.

The variables that you used were:

- Title, starttime, eventdate, endtime, description (*as a date*)

---

The script below follows the logic of your script. The main differences are:

- `getDataRange()` avoids the need to calculate last row, etc
- `getDisplayValues()` returns the date and time as strings, and *can* make it easier to add the time and date.
- created date/time (h/t [How to combine date and time into one element in google app script?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57285206/1330560). There may be a "better" way to do this; I shall leave that to others to suggest.

---

```
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form responses 1");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues()
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("<insert calendar id>");

  // start i at 1 to exclude header row
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++){
    // get the date and time
    var month = data[i][3].substring(4, 5);
    var day = data[i][3].substring(0, 2);
    var year = data[i][3].substring(6);
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: month: "+month+", day:"+day+", year: "+year)
    var startMinutes = data[i][4].substring(0, 2);
    var startHours = data[i][4].substring(3, 5);
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: start minutes: "+startMinutes+", start hours: "+startHours)
    var endMinutes = data[i][5].substring(0, 2);
    var endHours = data[i][5].substring(3, 5);
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: end minutes: "+endMinutes+", end hours: "+endHours)
    var startDate = new Date(month + " " + day + ", " + year + " " + startHours + ":" + startMinutes + ":00");
    var endDate = new Date(month + " " + day + ", " + year + " " + endHours + ":" + endMinutes + ":00");
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: start Date: "+startDate+", end date: "+endDate)

    // get the other variables
    var title = data[i][2]
    var desc = data[i][7]
    var loc = data[i][6]
    var options = {
      description: desc,
      location: loc
    }

    // create the event
    var event = cal.createEvent(title,startDate,endDate,options)

    Logger.log('Event ID: ' + event.getId())
  }
}
```

---

**Form SUBMISSION**

[image: submission]

---

**CALENDAR**

Note time difference is due to Time Zone (this calendar is in Austrealia)

[image: calendar]

---

**UPDATE**

This function, when installed as an `onFormSubmit` trigger will create an event as each new response is submitted.

```
// create an installable "onFormSubmit" trigger for this function

function formEventCreate(e) {
  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) // DEBUG

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form responses 1");
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("<insert ID>");

  // get the variables
  var title = e.values[2]
  var desc = e.values[7]
  var loc = e.values[6]
  var options = {
    description: desc,
    location: loc
  }

  // get the date and time
  var month = e.values[3].substring(4, 5);
  var day = e.values[3].substring(0, 2);
  var year = e.values[3].substring(6);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: month: "+month+", day:"+day+", year: "+year)
  var startMinutes = e.values[4].substring(3, 5);
  var startHours = e.values[4].substring(0,2);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: start minutes: "+startMinutes+", start hours: "+startHours)
  var endMinutes = e.values[5].substring(3, 5);
  var endHours = e.values[5].substring(0, 2);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: end minutes: "+endMinutes+", end hours: "+endHours)
  var startDate = new Date(month + " " + day + ", " + year + " " + startHours + ":" + startMinutes + ":00");
  var endDate = new Date(month + " " + day + ", " + year + " " + endHours + ":" + endMinutes + ":00");
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: start Date: "+startDate+", end date: "+endDate)

    // create the event
    var event = cal.createEvent(title,startDate,endDate,options)

    Logger.log('Event ID: ' + event.getId())
}
```

---

Comment: Keeps returning the first row as a calendar event so there's multiple events that are exactly the same but the most recent entry is missed.

Comment: This is something that you did not discuss in your question. Let's clarify... 1) How do you propose that this function is triggered - manually or by `onFormSubmit` trigger? 2) if by `onFormSubmit`, then do you want only the latest response to be processed?

Comment: Thank you for engaging with my problem.
1) Triger event on Form Submit
2) Yes the latest response to be processed every time

Problem:
I run a community diary website, it's a Google site and works with google calendars.
The log your event does not work very well especially for people who do not use an electronic calendar and cannot invite our calendar to their event.

Solution (I think)
Use a google form that will be resident on the website to enable people to directly record future events that will then appear online in the public community calendar.

Thanks again

Comment: @TJPhelps Refer the "UPDATE" script. Create an installable `onFormSubmit` trigger. The script will run as each new response is submitted; an event will be created ONLY for that new response.

Comment: I'm getting:
1:27:59 PM Error 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'values')
formEventCreate @ Post Stack Overflow 2.gs:11

Comment: Sounds like you're not picking up the Event Values. The function should include "e" in the name - as in `function formEventCreate(e) {`. Also, have you created an installable `onFormSubmit` trigger?

Comment: That's brilliant. I deleted the old trigger and reinstated a new one and it work fine now. Thanks so much for engaging with my problem and being the key to it's solution. Top marks,

Comment: For some reason this has stopped working and I can't figure out why.
  var title = e.values[2]
formEventCreate @ode:12

Comment: What does “Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))” return?

Comment: // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) // DEBUG

Comment: Riiight. I actually meant that you should delete the "//" in front of that line before you run it. But it looks like you have solved your problem - well done.